# Extracting time series data for each mesh in a data array

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am working on a data array with time, latitude and longitude dimensions. The data can be reproduced using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import xarray as xr

precipitation = 10 * np.random.rand(20, 40, 2880)
lon = range(20)
lat = range(40)
time = np.arange('2017-06-01', '2017-07-31', 
                  timedelta(minutes=30),dtype='datetime64[ns]')
data =xr.DataArray(
                   data=precipitation,
                   dims=["lon","lat","time"],
                   coords=[lon,lat,time])    
print (data)
```

I am willing to extract time series data for each mesh in the data array and store it in a csv file.

This is what I tried so far:

```
stacked_data = data.stack(z=("lon", "lat"))
for index in stacked_data.indexes["z"]:
    data = stacked_data.sel(z=index, drop=True)
    data_df=data.to_dataframe(name =str(index))
    data_df.to_csv("time series"+str(index)+".txt")
```

This method works fine with the example provided here. However it takes very long time when dealing with big data array created from time series raster files (many years for "time", thousands of "lon", and thousands of "lat").

Is there any other method that can do the job quickly?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow is simple and you are processing on a single machine, I'd suggest using `concurrent.futures` to dump the data to csv using multiple processes:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def dump_to_csv(x, ix):
    x = x.to_dataframe(name=str(ix))
    x.to_csv("temp/time series"+str(ix)+".txt")
    return True

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
    res = [pool.submit(dump_to_csv, stacked_data.sel(z=ix, drop=True), ix) for ix in stacked_data.indexes["z"]]
```

Of course, you can adjust the number of concurrent processes based on your requirements/hardware. You could also implement a more sophisticated way to check if the file was written, as it is in my quick example, you get a `True` returned in a `future`.

If your scale is bigger and/or involves multiple machines, you can look into [`dask.distributed`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/) and [`dask.delayed`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html). This way you could spread your data among workers and then write it to disk concurrently.

Comment: Thank you!
I succeeded to use "concurrent.futures" to create dump the data into csv file from the example data.
However, it takes so much time when using big data (>100,000 for time).
Could you provide an example of code using dask ?